# Facebook ShareLinkContent cut quote KitKat 4.4.4 (android api 19)

Tags: android, facebook, maven, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

So I use Android Studio 3.0.1, maven like this:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.27.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.27.0'
```

I followed everything from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

but when using Facebook ShareLinkContent like this:

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
  .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bei5000.debm&hl=in"))
  .setQuote(MyApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.game_yes_no_fb_quote, String.valueOf(playerScore * 1000)))
.build();

shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

I got inconsistent share content. on Redmi Xiaomi 2 Kitkat 4.4.4 API 19 the share content is:
[image: Share Content Displayed in Kitkat]

but on AVD Emulator Nexus 5X Nougat 7.0 API 24 the share content displayed is normal (no cut)
[image: Share Content Displayed in Nougat]

Why is this happened? For any help, Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: per @CBroe comment, I checked the actual share result and both are fine. but I still think this is a bug and should be reported to Facebook.

Comment: Have you checked what the actual share result looks like in each of the two cases? Maybe this is just an issue of the dialog, but the result will be fine nevertheless …?

Comment: wow! I didn't think that far. I just checked, the actual share result is fine. but I think this is a bug indeed.. it can confuse end user. where should I post a bug report to?

Comment: Try https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/